# How to redirect to home in react router dom after login with redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I wrote a reducer and a action for authentication in redux, and check if user logged in with:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isLoggedIn: state.auth.token !== null,
    }
}
```

it works, and i can check user auth in redner with:

```
if (this.props.isLoggedIn) {
    console.log('logged in');
}
```

After login get `logged in` in browser console.
How can i redirect to `/` ?

I try many way like:

```
if (this.props.isLoggedIn) {
    this.props.history.push('/');
}
```

Browser url changed but page content doesn't change.

Update:
My App.js routes:

```
  <div className="App">
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
      <Route path="/" component={Template} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
```

Update2: my template:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Template extends Component {
    render() {
           return (
            <h1>Template</h1>
        )
    }
}
export default Template;
```

Answer (score 1):

make your routes like this

```
<Switch>
      <Route exact path="/login" exact component={Login} />
      <Route path="/" component={Template} />
</Switch>
```

and then in your `Login` component's render method

```
this.props.isLoggedIn ? <Redirect to='/'/> : <div> { /* Login component stuff goes here */ } </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In render method

```
if (this.props.isLoggedIn) {
   return <Redirect to='/'/>;
}
```

I guess you have to import the below.

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yes, i checked it, url changed and page changed to white, my means is Template.js not rendering, i update my question and added my routes.

Comment: Did you check browser console? There could be some errors in console and hence template is not rendered

Comment: yes, there are no errors, my template is very simple, i added it to my question, please check it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Template} />
```

read more about [exact](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool)

tend to put your root route first inside `<Switch>` and for the last one you can have a route that will render in 404 cases.

from one of my projects

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
      <Route path='/auth' component={Auth} />
      <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dahsboard} />
      <Route component={Route404} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: i used `<Switch>` and if go to root `/` my template render but after redirect it not working.

Comment: your don't have 2 `Switch` components by any chance?

can you make a replica of your code on https://codesandbox.io/ so I can check it out. `this.props.history.push('/')` should work also, but obviously something is catching your route